# How to set Azure SQL database instance with Min 0,5 vCores with Terraform?

Tags: azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

I have Terraform and setting up Azure SQL database.

Currently Compute Hardware are defined as in Terraform:

requested_service_objective_name = "GP_S_Gen5_4"

This will configure Compute Hardware for Max vCores 4 and Min vCores 1.

I have need to configure min vCores as 0,5.
If I set up 0.5 and then deploy Terraform with "GP_S_Gen5_4", I get automatically upgraded to Min vCores 1.

Is there anything I can do to configure size as 0,5 or is 1 actual min when deployed by Terraform?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two terraform APIs, `azurerm_mssql_database` and `azurerm_mssql_elasticpool`.

The `azurerm_mssql_database` doesn't support vCore or DTU based database configuration. Only `azurerm_mssql_elasticpool` **v3.0** API allows for vCore and DTU based configurations.

Therefore, to declare the vCore using terraform, you need to deploy your database in Elastic Pool and use the below example code.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_elasticpool" "example" {
  name                = "test-epool"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.example.name
  license_type        = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb         = 756

  sku {
    name     = "BasicPool"
    tier     = "Basic"
    family   = "Gen4"
    capacity = 4
  }

  per_database_settings {
    min_capacity = 0.25
    max_capacity = 4
  }
}
```

Refer [azurerm_mssql_database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database) official document here.

Comment: -1: Your answer is incorrect. azurerm_mssql_elasticpool is something completely different from azurerm_mssql_database. These 2 APIs manage different resources. 

In Azure, the elastic pool is a resource you can use to manage and scale multiple databases sharing resources at a set price. You can also see this in the snippet you shared. There you don't specify a database name or collation for example.

Answer (score 4):

The resource `azurerm_mssql_database` does not have an attribute to set max vcores, it is specified in the last part of the `sku_name`. So if you want to have more max vcores, increase the sku. Set `min_capacity` to the minimum amount of vcores that you would need. Set `auto_pause_delay_in_minutes` to force the database to go into pause mode after x minutes of inactivity. This variable should be 60 minutes or higher, you can also set it to -1, which would leave the database running on the minimum capacity.

I would not recommend using `azurerm_mssql_elasticpool` if you need a normal sql database, it has other purposes. See below or read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases#general-purpose---serverless-compute---gen5):

[image]

Some general recommendations/guidelines:

- If you need a fast scaling database, don't set the minimum amount of vcores too low. Vcore scaling also takes some time to propagate.
- Set databases in development and testing environments to auto-pause delay to save costs when not used. Preferably to the minimum of 60 minutes.
- For frequently used production environments, set auto pause delay to -1.
- The database will generally take some time to start after the first request. Your application has to be able to handle connection retries when the database is paused. I have seen applications that did not do this properly, resulting in wierd behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by the accepted answer, there are two terraform APIs for SQL databases, but note that it is [azurerm_sql_database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_database) (deprecated), and [azurerm_mssql_database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database) which is the now standard.

Unlike the accepted answer, I would suggest to be careful, [azurerm_mssql_elasticpool](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_elasticpool) is **something else entirely**, and allows you to spread resources over several databases. From your question, I don't believe you need to set this up, as it will only increase your costs.

Using the official module, I've had no trouble specifying a minimum capacity of `0.5`, there's a setting for this, `min_capacity`, which seems functional to me. It defaults to `0`, though, which is not an accepted value, so be sure to set it. For instance the following configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "this" {
  name                         = "demo-min-capacity"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "..."
  administrator_login_password = "..."
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "this" {
  name           = "demo"
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.this.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  max_size_gb    = 20

  sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_1"
  zone_redundant              = false
  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = 60
  min_capacity                = 0.5

  storage_account_type = "LRS"
}
```

resulted in this setting on the azure portal:
[image]