# Can't set max vCores through ARM template for SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to set the storage details of a SQL database through an ARM template. I want the maximum amount of vCores to be set to 2. However, the setting always defaults to 1. The rest of the properties work just fine.

I can't find anything on MSDN regarding a maxCapacity property, even though there is a minCapacity property. I found a few people on Stackoverflow talking about a maxCapacity property, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's a snippet from my template:

```
"properties": {
    "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
    "maxSizeBytes": 268435456000,
    "catalogCollation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
    "zoneRedundant": false,
    "readScale": "Disabled",
    "highAvailabilityReplicaCount": 0,
    "minCapacity": 0.5,
    "maxCapacity": 2,
    "autoPauseDelay": 60,
    "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": "Geo",
    "isLedgerOn": "false",
    "availabilityZone": "NoPreference",
    "useFreeLimit": "false",
    "freeLimitExhaustionBehavior": "AutoPause",
    "maintenanceConfigurationId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Maintenance/publicMaintenanceConfigurations/SQL_Default')]"
  }
```

[Here's a screenshot of the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sv2R.png)

Comment: There is no specific attribute to set maxvcores for sql database. Inorder to set the maximum capacity, it has to be specified in the SKU itself. You can just increase the limit of SKU. Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases?view=azuresql#general-purpose---serverless-compute---gen5). @Luuk

Comment: You can also refer [this](https://www.yobyot.com/azure/example-arm-template-azure-sql-vcore-failover-group-elasticpool/2020/02/04/).

Comment: I have remove the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_, Instead yoy should add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, it does not have a specific attribute to set the maximum number of `vCores`; instead, it can be provided in the `sku` capacity itself. After a workaround on your requirement, I found that increasing `sku` will be useful to set up more maximum vcores.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases?view=azuresql) to check resource limits, capacities using the vCore model & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641442/19785512) by @Cloudkollektiv for more related information.

```bash
"sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "Capacity": 2
      }
```

By referring to the sample template from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-arm-template-quickstart?view=azuresql) to create a sql database, I tried to reproduce it in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.12.40.16777",
      "templateHash": "16856611863128783179"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "serverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uniqueString('sql', resourceGroup().id)]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "sqlDB": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "administratorLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
      "type": "secureString",
      "metadata": {
        "description": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('server')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('server'), parameters('sqlDB'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
      "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
      "minCapacity": 0.5,
      "createMode": "Default"
   },
   "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('server'))]"
   ],
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "Capacity": 2
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('server'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Output:*

[image]